# Ruby incorrectly interpreting class namespace

Tags: ruby

I have code that looks like the following snippet:

```
require_relative 'class/foo'
require_relative 'class/bar'
require_relative 'class/baz'

class MyClass
  def initialize(arg)
    ...

    %w(wordone wordtwo).each do |word|
      Foo.public_send(word.to_sym, arg)
      Bar.public_send(word.to_sym, arg)
      Baz.public_send(word.to_sym, arg)
    end
  end
end
```

In each of those three requires is code like this template:

```
class Foo
  def self.wordone(arg)
    # do stuff
  end

  def self.wordtwo(arg)
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

This works perfectly fine for `Foo` and `Bar`, but once it hits `Baz`:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant MyClass::Baz
Did you mean?  Baz
```

I clearly specified `Baz` and not `MyClass::Baz`. Why is Ruby randomly misinterpreting the namespace for the third object method invocation and not the first two?

I should also mention that if I change:

```
Baz.public_send(word.to_sym, arg)
```

to:

```
Baz.wordone(arg)
```

then it works perfectly for that one method invocation, but I obviously need to loop over multiple method invocations for that class. So Ruby's namespace misinterpretation seems to be linked to the use of `public_send` on the object method.

This is occurring on Ruby 2.3.1p112.

Comment: Hmm, maybe don't call your class `Class`. :-)

Comment: @mwp I can edit the snippet to have it be something other than Class. I should change the formatting a little too I guess.

Comment: Can you give us a full, reproductible minimal example? My crystal ball is broken.

Comment: Most likely because for whatever reason `Baz` isn't actually defined (though I can't really say why from just the code above).

Comment: Okay, so it's not actually called `Class`? Basically what's happening here is Ruby can't find class `Baz` at the top-level, so it's looking under `MyClass`. Can you show us your `Baz` class?

Comment: @Nax This is a full reproducible example.

Comment: @mwp Thanks for the suggestion. I have checked and double-checked that class `Baz` is available and this was working fine back when I invoked with `Baz.wordone(arg)` instead of the `public_send`, but I will triple-check.

Comment: @mwp I just solved it and your comment lead me to the correct solution. Could you convert your comment into an answer please?

Comment: Done. Glad I could help, although I must admit I'm still a bit mystified!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codifying my (apparently helpful) comment from the OP:

Basically what's happening here is Ruby can't find class `Baz` at the top-level, so it's looking under `MyClass` (it actually tries looking under `MyClass` first, then checks the top-level; the error message tells you that it couldn't find it in either namespace).

Answer (score 1):

It seems some characters are being escaped in the string passed into the block

Upon inspection,

`$('wordone wordtwo').each {|word| p word}`

gives

`"\"wordone\""` and `"\"wordtwo\""`

Removing the extra escaped string quotes and forward slash gets it working for me.

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(arg)
    ...

    %w(wordone wordtwo).each do |word|
      word = word.tr('\"', '');
      Foo.public_send(word.to_sym, arg)
      Bar.public_send(word.to_sym, arg)
      Baz.public_send(word.to_sym, arg)
    end
  end
end
```

You could check that, let's see how it goes

Comment: Sorry, same issue. It seems I have found a bug in Ruby and will have to figure out whether to hackily work around it or report it.

Comment: Uh uh. . . Well, we tried. Do report. I'd definitely encourage that :)